# Prism - Region with IActiveAware not called on initial load

Tags: silverlight, prism

I have regions within a TabControl that load fine when I click the tab headers but I cannot set a default view when the page initially loads.

Ex: If I have 3 tabs, I want the first one loaded by default. Easiest way to do this?

Comment: The easiest way, I think, just bind `SelectedIndex`. Won't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

After InitializeComponent() in the constructor

TabControl.SelectedItem = TabControl.Items[0];

Did not test it though